# Unity3d game in IOS crashing after changing to second scene?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, unity-game-engine

Game used to work fine; I believe it was after upgrading Unity to 4.5 that the error appeared. The game Shows an image in the first scene, which is displayed correctly. After changing scene, though, the game crashes.

On the XCode debugger I keep seeing the message "EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0x7ffdefe)"

The console displays the following messages:

```
2014-07-05 16:10:22.996 MyGame[5934:707] <Google> Test ads are only available on iOS 6+.

Unhandled Exception: UnityEngine.UnityException: WWW is not finished downloading yet
  at UnityEngine.WWW.get_responseHeaders () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GoogleAnalytics.LogScreen (System.String title) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LogoGlow.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/iPhonePlayer-armv7Generated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
```

In the Unity editor,  I get the "WWW is not finished downloading yet" error, but the game runs just fine (only without ads), and I am able to run it perfectly on Android.

I'm sorry for the lack of information, but its the first time I use Unity/Xcode and I haven't been able to find anything useful online :/

Comment: Are you running on a device or simulator? Also, are you using a `GoogleAnalytics` library? It looks like it's hitting a bad url or it's not downloading something fast enough / your app isn't waiting long enough.

Comment: I'm running on a device. Tested the app on two different devices with the same result, one with 7.0 IOS version and another with 5.1

Comment: I get the exact same error overtime i open my scene[2]. And only some times the applications stops responding. and my script call is set to safe and slow. do you think it has to do with my preloader? (Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/iPhonePlayer-armv7Generated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)

Answer (score 3):

One thing that is important to keep in mind is that Unity3D will continue to run a project even when there are runtime errors. It may not mean that everything will run as expected, but sometimes the subtle differences can be hard to see. It is not uncommon for an error to not cause a hangup in Unity, but to cause a crash on your iOS device.

So what I would is go back to your Unity script and start exactly where the Xcode log suggested, i.e., at LogoGlow.Start(). I know this is a pain, but comment out every line in that Start() method, and add them back in one by one, each time running it until the error occurs in Unity. Then, try to determine what it is that you're doing before the download finishes that you shouldn't be doing. I can't see your code, but are you yielding on your www download? (yield www;)

If you want to post the relevant code from your Unity script, it may help a bit. But I would just reiterate that this type of scenario is not uncommon when building for iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I just downgraded Unity and the game still crashes with the same XCode error but with none of the console's Unity-related errors. The LogoGlow() function initialized GoogleAnalytics, I believe that's why it was being mentioned, but after the downgrade not GoogleAnalytics nor LogoGlow() are mentioned on the console. I can't find anything on the subcode=0x7ffdefe

Answer (score 2):

Whelp, I fixed it by changing the Script Call Optimization option on the player settings in Unity to "Slow and Safe". Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Sorry for bringing this up again but I'm facing similar issue where I fixed it by changing the Script Call Optimization to "Slow And Safe". Now I'm thinking whether this is the right way of fixing the issue? I think for the release build we should always use "Fast and No Exceptions" But I couldn't find out what's causing the crashing to happen. It happens to me during change scene and it kinda happen randomly.

Does anyone can provide better solution besides changing the Script Call Optimization? I'm just feeling this solution is kinda lying to yourself in order to bypass the error?